# I need help with this Aura of statement. How to write an if statement if field one cannot be equal or greater than field two?

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, aura, aura-if

I need help with my Aura if statement.There are two time fields that the Start time can not be equal to or greater than the end time?

I tried to write out the aura if statement but I am getting stuck if someone can explain it to me in detail. thank you

Comment: This question is the same as your last question, where you got a detailed answer. If you are still not clear on the problem, please be _more detailed_ in your question. Describe _why_ you are asking this question and give background on what you are trying to do.

Comment: As written, this markup is incorrect; it appears you've added attributes of an input field to your `<aura:if>` tag, but it's not clear why.